# Execute code within Apple Keynote

Tags: server, keynote

I'm trying to send some code to a remote server everytime I change a slide on Keynote. Is this possible? Can I add code to be executed on keynote?

Basically, everytime a user changes a slide, it sends a POST request to a server with a string as a parameter.

Thank you!